# Stacked line charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I need to create a trend line where the series all have similar values so in order to show the actual trends, I would like to separate the lines, similar to the image below.  The chart below is using what PowerPoint calls a stacked line chart.

[image: Powerpoint stacked line chart]

The problem is that while the value labels populate correctly, the direction of the line may trend in the opposite direction.  (See the gold line from wave 5 to 6 - the line should be going up).

Comment: I don't think it is the type of chart that's the issue.  When you format your data labels, did you set the `Label Contains` to `Value`?

Comment: Yes, that is how it's set.  It's being referred to as a 'stacked line chart' where the lines don't overlap because they are cumulative at each point.  I don't need them to be cumulative but I do need them to be separated.  A standard line chart would make it difficult to see each series/group and their labels because all of the values are very similar.

Comment: That's the issue.  Sorry that I missed that.  When you use stacked line charts, the individual lines are showing the trend of the sum of all the values below it.  Recommend that you use a regular line chart and then format the vertical axis to have, as an example, a minimum of 5% and maximum of 25% to give you some separation.  Play with those values to get the look you want.

Comment: I clarified my original post so you didn't miss anything :)  The issue with a regular line chart is that the values are so similar and there are 4 lines so there's overlap and it makes it difficult to read.  I was hoping there was a solution similar to the stacked line chart that allowed for the separation of the lines. [see regular line chart][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbyi1.png

Comment: @user939482, I've  successfully reproduced  the Graph and not found any such problem as you have said, "gold line from wave 5 to 6 - the line should be going up". What  I did I've tried both Line with marker & Stacked line with Markers. ☺

Answer (score 1):

A stacked line chart will distort your trends because they are trending to the sum of all the values below, not the value for that line.

As I stated in my comments, this is one way around it.  I don't claim it is the only or best way, but stacked lines are not a solution.

[image: Regular Line chart]

In this, I took your data and created a regular line chart.  I changed the vertical axis to have min of 8% and max of 24%.  I also made it a little taller proportionally, which you often need to do to get the kind of separation for similar values.  Additionally I played with the data labels, some right, some top, and some bottom.  You can also select individual data label boxes and move them around to help with clarity.